# Деинициализируется Presenter при показе View

Tags: ios, swift

Столкнулся с довольно странной ситуацией. Пишу приложение по паттерну VIPER. Деинициализируется Presenter при показе View перед viewWillAppear, но после viewDidLoad.
Фрагмент кода из Wireframe:

```
startVC.presenter = signInPresenter
signInPresenter.delegate = startVC
signInPresenter.interactor = signInInteractor
signInInteractor.presenter = signInPresenter
self.showVC(vc: startVC as! SignInViewController)
```

Фрагмент кода из View:

```
weak var presenter: SignInControllerPresenterProtocol?
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.presenter?.checkForSavedUser()
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.animateFirstResp()
}
```

При том, если объявить presenter как strong, связь сохраняется.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пока писал вопрос, понял ответ. Возможно, кому-то будет полезно. ViewController присваивается внешней переменной со strong-связью в Wireframe. Если объявить presenter как weak, на него не остается ссылок и он будет уничтожен, так же как и interactor и прочие. Но если в ViewController объявить их связь с presenter как Strong, ничего не деинициализируется до тех пор, пока не будет уничтожен ViewController.